Apply space on the next line (not the current line)
My code should run as below:

But in CLion it is executed as follows:


When I add a space (spaces), instead of being applied to the current line, it is applied to the next line.
How do I solve this problem?
In addition, it has nothing to do with the size of the code runner, because I have this problem with any size.
The text below is the code that I run.
#include <iostream>

int getNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    return (num1 + num2) * (num1 - num2);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, welcome to program\n";
    std::cout << "This program performs mathematical calculations on the inputs.\n\n";

    std::cout << "Enter two numbers (with space):          ";
    int num1 { 0 };
    int num2 { 0 };
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    std::cout << "The numbers are: " << getNumbers(num1, num2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}

It should be applied to the space CLion on the current line.  It shouldn't be applied to the next line when I apply a space, which is a problem.  In general, the following pictures say it all.
Correctly apply spaces in cmd:

Improper spacing in CLion:



Please check the following ticket (and related) -- try the workarounds -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-17579

Thank you @LazyOne You solved my problem
